# Selecting few checkboxes under a div using jquery by matching names with an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <div id="menu" class="dropdown-menu hold-on-click dropdown-checkboxes pull-right">
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '1'>1</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = "2'>2</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '3'>3</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '4'>4</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '5'>5</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox0" data-column="0" name = '6'>6</label>
</div>
```

var columns = ['2','5','6'];

I want to set all the check-boxs whos name is present in `columns` array available under the a `div` to be checked using jQuery. I googled and found multiple solutions where user is checking all the check-box available under a `div` but my problem is all the checkboxes inside the `div` are placed under a `label` & i want to select only those columns whos name is present in `columns` array.

Please help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/417/ $("#menu").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true);

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
$('#menu').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

Note: **IDs must be unique.**

```
var columns = ['2','5','6'];
$("#menu").find("input[type='checkbox']").filter(function(){
    return columns.indexOf($(this).attr('name')) > -1;
}).prop("checked",true);
```

[**DEMo**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/eug5q5nv/)

Comment: Thank you the reply. My apology. I have updated the question. Please look at the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery attribute selector for this.

```
var columns = ['2','5','6'];
$.each( columns, function( key, value ) {
    $("#menu :checkbox[name='"+value+"']").prop("checked",true);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/418/)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Where are you specifying the div. i assume this code will run for all the checkboxes in the page

Comment: I am using a framework called emberjs and it has a problem with `'"+value+"'`. it thorws an error saying string must use singlequotes. any alternatives? ?

Comment: remove the single quote and try again

Comment: I mean the code should use single quotes not the double quotes. I am not sure if I follow you. Thank you looking into this

Comment: how about this ? $('#menu :checkbox[name='+value+']').prop("checked",true);